# Convert string to compiled regex matching the exact string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Is there a simple way to transform an exact string matching to a `re.compile` object ? For example, I would like to mix exact string and regexes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can probably use [`re.escape`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) to escape everything in a string, and then use the escaped string as a pattern.

```
def transform(s):
    return re.compile(re.escape(s))
```

Comment: I feel a lot ashamed. So simple... Thanks for this !